# MVC4 Deserializing JSON object in Controller

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I just fixed a problem with the above. I was sending a JSON object to a controller, but once inside the controller method the object's attributes were all null.

The fix was to add { get; set; } to all the properties of the object in its class. The properties were already public but that was not enough.

Can anyone tell me why this is so?

Comment: How's the model binder going to set the properties of the model if there are no setters?

Comment: Why can't it just use the traditional method - object.property = blah ? the properties are declared public

Comment: Maybe posting an example of the JSON that is being passed to the controller, and the class that's being bound to will help understand the problem.

Comment: I fixed the problem I had. What I want is an explanation why setters are needed by the model binder if the properties are public.

Comment: Apparently due to the way that the model binders work?  See http://pollirrata.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/public-field-not-bound-when-posting-to.html

Comment: Thanks for the article link. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

To make it an answer, if you look at the MVC [DefaultModelBinder.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) code, on binding complex element you can see modelbinder binds only the properties of the model.

```
internal void BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, object model)
  {
            // need to replace the property filter + model object and create an inner binding context
            ModelBindingContext newBindingContext = CreateComplexElementalModelBindingContext(controllerContext, bindingContext, model);  
            // validation
            if (OnModelUpdating(controllerContext, newBindingContext))
            {
                BindProperties(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
                OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
            }
   }
```